# Filter and delete row

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I am trying to create a Excel VBA for sheet based on below criteria.

- The sheet contains users list and permission list of different folders in file share.
- The requirement is to filter the user and if permission contains full control then delete other rows for that user.

[image]

In the above example, FirstUser has 4 entries of Permission in Input. But in output, we need to get the one permission with highest permission level.
Similarly, for seconduser, 3 permission entries are present and the highest permission level is Modify, Synchronize. So the output should contain only one entry and delete other entries.

Any pointers will be helpful..!!

Comment: You need a table or array of possible permissions, ordered from highest to lowest.  Loop over the "input" rows and compare each permission to the table/array to see if it's the highest yet for that user.  You can use a scripting dictionary, or track the level in the output table.  The best thing is to try to make a start, then post back with your code if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general code:

```
Sub SubReport()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim StrReportName1 As String
    Dim StrReportName2 As String
    Dim StrSourceName As String
    Dim StrSourceAddress As String
    Dim StrAccessoryAddress As String
    Dim RngSource As Range
    Dim RngTarget As Range
    Dim RngPermission As Range
    Dim RngPermissionList As Range
    Dim WksWorksheet01 As Worksheet
    
    'Settings
    StrSourceAddress = "A1:B1" 'Specify here the address of the headers of the table with data.
    StrAccessoryAddress = "D1" 'This address just have to be outside of StrSourceAddress.
    StrReportName1 = " - Permission levels"
    StrReportName2 = " - Filtered Report"
    
    'Evaluating the situation.
    Select Case True
        'Checking if the active sheet does not contain StrReportName1 nor StrReportName2 at the end of its name.
        Case Is = Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(StrReportName1)) <> StrReportName1 And _
                  Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(StrReportName2)) <> StrReportName2
            
            'Setting.
            StrSourceName = ActiveSheet.Name
            
            'Covering each worksheet of the workbook.
            For Each WksWorksheet01 In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                'If a sheet with StrReportName1 at the end of its name already exists, the macro is interrupted.
                If WksWorksheet01.Name = StrSourceName & StrReportName1 Then
                    MsgBox "A sheet named " & StrSourceName & StrReportName1 & "already exists. Rename said sheet in order to run the macro correctly.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Rename sheet"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
            
            'Creating a copy of the active sheet.
            ActiveSheet.Copy ActiveSheet
            
            'Renaming the active sheet.
            ActiveSheet.Name = StrSourceName & StrReportName1
            
            'Settings.
            Set RngSource = Range(StrSourceAddress)
            Set RngSource = Range(RngSource.Offset(1, 0), RngSource.End(xlDown))
            Set RngPermission = Range(StrAccessoryAddress)
            
            'Creating entire new columns as accessory range.
            RngPermission.EntireColumn.Insert
            RngPermission.EntireColumn.Insert
            Set RngPermission = RngPermission.Offset(0, -2)
            
            'Reporting the name of the original sheet.
            RngPermission.Value = StrSourceName
            
            'Creating the headers for the permission table.
            Set RngPermission = RngPermission.Offset(2, 0)
            RngPermission.Value = "Permission name"
            RngPermission.Offset(0, 1) = "Permission level (the higher, the greater)"
            Set RngPermission = RngPermission.Offset(1, 0)
            
            'Covering the whole permissions' column of RngSource.
            For Each RngTarget In RngSource.Columns(2).Cells
                'Reporting each unique permission.
                If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(RngSource.Columns(2).Cells(1, 1), RngTarget), RngTarget.Value) = 1 Then
                    RngPermission.Value = RngTarget.Value
                    Set RngPermission = RngPermission.Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next
            
            'Settings.
            Set RngPermission = RngPermission.Offset(-1, 0)
            Set RngPermissionList = Range(RngPermission.End(xlUp), RngPermission.Offset(0, 1))
            
            'Visual editing.
            RngPermissionList.Columns.AutoFit
            RngPermissionList.Borders.Weight = xlThin
            RngPermissionList.Rows(1).Font.Bold = True
            RngPermissionList.Cells(2, 2).Select
            RngPermissionList.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            Set RngTarget = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            RngPermissionList.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            RngTarget.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            RngPermissionList.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Set RngTarget = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            RngPermissionList.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            RngTarget.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            
            MsgBox "Specify the permission level for each permission. Then run again the macro.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Specify permission level"
            
        'Checking if the active sheet contains StrReportName1 at the end of its name.
        Case Is = Right(ActiveSheet.Name, Len(StrReportName1)) = StrReportName1
            
            'Setting.
            StrSourceName = Range(StrAccessoryAddress).Value
            
            'Covering each worksheet of the workbook.
            For Each WksWorksheet01 In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
                'If a sheet with StrReportName2 at the end of its name already exists, the macro is interrupted.
                If WksWorksheet01.Name = StrSourceName & StrReportName2 Then
                    MsgBox "A sheet named " & StrSourceName & StrReportName2 & "already exists. Rename said sheet in order to run the macro correctly.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Rename sheet"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            Next
            
            'Visual editing.
            Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            
            'Settings.
            Set RngSource = Range(StrSourceAddress)
            Set RngSource = Range(RngSource.Offset(1, 0), RngSource.End(xlDown))
            Set RngPermissionList = Range(StrAccessoryAddress).Offset(2, 0)
            Set RngPermissionList = RngPermissionList.Resize(1, 2)
            Set RngPermissionList = Range(RngPermissionList.Offset(1, 0), RngPermissionList.End(xlDown))
            
            'Creating an acessory new entire column.
            RngSource.Offset(0, RngSource.Columns.Count).Resize(RngSource.Rows.Count, 1).EntireColumn.Insert
            
            'Setting.
            Set RngSource = RngSource.Resize(RngSource.Rows.Count, RngSource.Columns.Count + 1)
            
            'Reporting what levels of permission each user has.
            RngSource.Columns(3).Value = Excel.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(RngSource.Columns(2).Value, RngPermissionList, 2, False)
            
            'Sorting RngSource.
            With ActiveSheet.Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add Key:=RngSource.Columns(1), _
                                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, _
                                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SortFields.Add Key:=RngSource.Columns(3), _
                                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlDescending, _
                                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SetRange RngSource
                .Header = xlGuess
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
                .SortFields.Clear
            End With
            
            'Covering the whole users' column of RngSource.
            For Each RngTarget In RngSource.Columns(1).Cells
                'Clearing all rows but one for each user.
                If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(RngSource.Columns(1).Cells(1, 1), RngTarget), RngTarget.Value) > 1 Then
                    Range(RngTarget, RngTarget.Offset(0, RngSource.Columns.Count - 1)).Clear
                End If
            Next
            
            'Sorting RngSource.
            With ActiveSheet.Sort
                .SortFields.Clear
                .SortFields.Add Key:=RngSource.Columns(1), _
                                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                                Order:=xlAscending, _
                                DataOption:=xlSortNormal
                .SetRange RngSource
                .Header = xlGuess
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
                .SortFields.Clear
            End With
            
            'Deleting accessory columns.
            RngSource.Columns(3).EntireColumn.Delete
            RngPermissionList.EntireColumn.Delete
            
            'Renaming the active sheet.
            ActiveSheet.Name = StrSourceName & StrReportName2
            
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

Make sure the lines `StrSourceAddress = "A1:B1"` and `StrAccessoryAddress = "D1"` are properly edited. Select the sheet the data are on and run the code. On a first run the code create a list of unique permissions in a new sheet. The user then has to specify to what level each permission corresponds to. Once done, the user has to run the code again. It will then create the desired result.

A way shorter and better solution to the problem can be obtained with more information about the data you have (expecially if you already have a list of all the possible permissions with matching level). Still this code should do the trick.